# Attempting to install Clarinet on raspberry pi 3b

Tags: raspberry-pi, clarity

I downloaded clarinet from [here](https://github.com/hirosystems/clarinet) and am following the installation guide, however I get this error when installing on a raspberry pi:

```
failed to add native library/home/pi/clarity/clarinet/target/release/gn_out/obj/librusty_v8.a: file too small to be an archive
```

Does anyone know how to fix this/install clarinet on a raspberry pi?

Comment: it may just be that the download of librusty_v8.a failed, so try deleting the file, and rebuild, possibly from scratch with clean first
and check your device is not out of disk space

Comment: you need to provide more relevant details to help people answer your question (detailed OS/compiler environment, full command output)

Answer (score 0):

without knowing much about your environment, to build on arm, there are few things you should be aware of:

- there is no `musl` support, `clang` is probably best (https://github.com/denoland/rusty_v8/issues/49, I know it says x86_64, but probably same issues on arm)
- there is no prebuilt arm binaries (https://github.com/denoland/rusty_v8/releases/)

so you'll probably need to build `rusty_v8` from source